# Flutter web is not responsive to screen size unless I refresh the browser or hot restart the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to build a responsive app by using MediaQuery to get the screen size but it doesn't update to the widgets I planned to use for the different screen sizes when I resize the browsers.

I am running it on Chrome but have also tried it on Edge. Initially, it starts okay but then doesn't respond as expected when I resize the browser. I was hoping it will toggle between the "on Mobile" or "on Desktop" as I resize Chrome but it only updates if I refresh the browser or restart the app. I am using Flutter 2.0.4.  Please inform me what I have missed. Thanks!

I get the screen size here (intentionally left out Tablet):

```
enum DeviceScreenType {
  Mobile,
  Desktop
}

class DeviceInfo {

  static DeviceScreenType getDeviceScreenType(MediaQueryData mediaQueryData) {
    double deviceWidth = mediaQueryData.size.width;

    if (deviceWidth <= 768) {
      return DeviceScreenType.Mobile;
    }
    else {
      return DeviceScreenType.Desktop;
    }
  }
}
```

Then based on that, I use it here. I was building a list view in a Stateless class but because it wasn't working, I am just using a dummy text for testing for now.

```
Widget _desktopList () => Center(child: Text("On Desktop"),);

Widget _mobileList () =>  Center(child: Text("On Mobile"));

Widget _getDeviceScreenType (BuildContext context){

    MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);

    var deviceInfo = DeviceInfo.getDeviceScreenType(mediaQueryData);
    DeviceScreenType deviceScreenType = DeviceScreenType.Desktop;
    return deviceInfo == deviceScreenType?_desktopList () : _mobileList();
  }
```

Here is the build widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _getDeviceScreenType(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are not passing the correct `context` to the `_getDeviceScreenType`. It should be the context provided by the `build` method. It's better to call such functions at the top of the `build` to avoid such confusions.

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves I have the methods above the build method. I have also made it below it and but have the same results. Thanks

Comment: There are two functions that are providing different `context`: The `build` method and `itemBuilder` callback. The `context` that you are passing to `_getDeviceScreenType ` is of the `itemBuilder` which is incorrect. You can change the code `(BuildContext context, int index)` to `(BuildContext _, int index)`.

Comment: I can't mark your comment as the accepted answer because of my account but it has solved my issue. I have upvoted it. Thanks